# NavigationView does not hide automatically

Tags: java, android

After starting the application for the first time I have a problem with NavigationView. Namely, when I expand navigation view and click on Conventional you can see that the fragment with the red background appears, but NavigationView does not disappear automatically, I have to hide it manually. How can I fix it?

[image]

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, 0, 0);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();

                switch(itemId) {

                    case R.id.conventional:
                       FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                       manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_main, new fragment_conventional()).commit();
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @UnkownBoy, Does bellow solution worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is working code for me

Please update your `actionBarDrawerToggle` accordingly

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        //drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```